# Regex Search for absence of a string inside a string multiline

Tags: regex, splunk

I have an xml file with a bunch of query strings.  I need to check for the absence of a command in each query.

Simplistically, I can identify a string which does not contain the substring.  The pattern here correctly and only matches the 2nd row.  Easy enough.

```
aa((?<!bb).)*?dd

aa-ee-bb-cc-dd
aa-ee-cc-dd
```

But when I attempt this in larger and multiline strings in my xml file, it captures all strings, even ones which contain the substring.

Goal: Look for strings inside of <query> element without "sistats" somewhere in it and not leak into the next query.

Here all 4 query strings are matched, even ones containing sistats.  Only the bottom 3 should match.

```
(?s)(<search\s+id=".+?">).*?<query>((?<!sistats).)*?((?<!<\/search>).)*?<\/query>

<form>
  <search id="id1">
    <query>index=asdf
| fields asdf
| sistats count</query>
  </search>
  <search id="id2">
    <query>index=asdf
| fields asdf
| chart count</query>
  </search>
  <search id="id3">
    <query>index=asdf
| fields asdf
| sitimechart
| table asdf</query>
  </search>
  <search id="id4">
    <query>index=asdf
| table asdf</query>
  </search>
  <row>
    <panel>
```

https://regex101.com/r/V4ztar/1

How can i match only the bottom 3?

Comment: That should be a lookahead inside the tempered greedy token, `aa(?:(?!bb).)*?dd`. In general though, do not parse XML with regex. There are better ways for this.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no other way.  It needs to be a Splunk query and I'm looking for inefficiencies.  I only have Regex available for this.

Comment: I think you want `(?s)(<search\s+id="[^"]*">)[^<]*<query>(?:(?!sistats).)*?<\/query>`, see https://regex101.com/r/oCgTHw/1. And no, this is not a duplicate, since I'd have closed it at the very start. Although very close to one.

Comment: This works.  Thank you!  And yes there are close answers which I struggled modifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `((?<!sistats).)` with `(?:(?!sistats).)` and remove the group `((?<!<\/search>).)`.

Check this [demo](https://tools.waytolearnx.com/fr/regex-tester/c66a0d26bfa6)

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into [`mvfilter`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/MultivalueEvalFunctions#mvfilter.28.26lt.3Bpredicate.26gt.3B.29) - once the data is in multivalue fields in Splunk, you can do something like the following:

```
| eval missing_item_list = mvfilter(!match(full_list,"bb"))
```

Comment: I think this can also work.